# ListView with custom ArrayAdapter not showing items

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So I'm trying to create a custom ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter.
I got a fragment that loads the ListView, creating and setting my own ArrayAdapter called **CardsAdapter**.

Problem? The list is not showing up. Only the default text (android:id="@android:id/empty"), that is set to show if the list is empty, shows up.

For matters of testing this method `cards.createDummy();` fills up the list with 3 dummy objects to be shown.

Fragment where I declare and create the listview

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements Callback{

private ListView listView;
private CardsAdapter cardsAdapter;
private CardList cards; //contains the array to be shown

public MainFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cards = new CardList(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    cards.createDummy();  //Fills up dummy list

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    //Creates the adapter with the dummy list cards.cardList
    cardsAdapter = new CardsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),cards.cardList);
    listView.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);

    //don't bother with this
    HttpHandle handle = new HttpHandle( listView, this);
    handle.download("http://someapp.herokuapp.com/");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

The layout file of the list view (correspondent to `R.layout.fragment_main`)
I've got the list, and a textview to be shown if the list is empty:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#E6E6E6" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E6E6E6"
    android:text="Retrieving data"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CardsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
public LinearLayout cardView;

public CardsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList cards) {
    super(context, R.layout.card, cards);
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
    }

    Card card = getItem(position);

    this.cardView = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);

    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(card.getTitle());

    return rowView;
}
}
```

The card layout used by the CardsAdapter (referenced on the constructor as `R.layout.card`)
file: `res/layout/card.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="True"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/photo" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@string/title"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/dateStart"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Note:
The dummy list is created and is not empty: I checked it with the debug tools
The app runs, and does not crash.  But it only shows the empty TextView

Comment: Show you *xml* file please and the code where you check whether the list is emtpy or not to toggle the visibility of the **textView**

Comment: By declaring the id of the textview as 'android:id="@android:id/empty"', the android knows to show this text if the list is empty. It's automatic. Note that the id is an android default '@android:id/empty' as opposed to '@+id/empty'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't toggle the visibility of the **TextView** to be invisible if the **ListView** is empty, try to remove the **TextView** and run the application, the **ListView** should appear.

Using Empty TextView you should either make your *activity* extends **ListViewActivity** or you have to set the empty **TextView** for **ListView** in *Java* using `listView.setEmptyView(youTextView);` to handle the toggle of visibility.

Comment: check my answer update to let the empty textview be shown if the listView is really empty